# Cannot Register saga using Masstransit.Integration.AspNetCore

Tags: masstransit

I cannot register saga using Masstransit.AspNetCore package, it results on this error. I'm using Default Container with error "No service for type 'Automatonymous.Registration.ISagaStateMachineFactory' has been registered"

```
e.AddSagaStateMachine<CityAvailabilityStateMachine, CityAvailabilityState>(new NullSagaStateMachineRegistrar());
    e.AddBus(provider =>{
                    var credentials = provider.GetService<Credential>();
                    return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
                    {
                        var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(credentials.Uri), h =>
                        {
                            h.Username(credentials.UserName);
                            h.Password(credentials.Password);
                            h.Heartbeat(60);
                        });

                        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host,{credentials.BoundedContext}-sagas", configurator =>
                        {
                            configurator.PrefetchCount = 16;
                            configurator.UseRetry(r => r.Interval(2, 100));
                            configurator.ConfigureSaga<CityAvailabilityState>(provider);
                        });
                    });
```

Comment: You need to add the [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MassTransit.Automatonymous.Extensions.DependencyInjection/5.3.2) for MS DI, to get it registered. That NullSagaStateMachineRegistrar() should be a clue that you're missing something.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I installed the package and used DependencyInjectionSagaStateMachineRegistrar and it's working now